# Ionic2 Move fab button above keyboard in ios

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic2 fab button at bottom to display fab button. In android this button moves up when keyboard is shown but in ios it stays behind the keyboard. I think this is the default functionality of ionic for ios. But can anyone help getting the same behaviour in ios(ionic2) below is my code.

```
   <button id="as_confirmButtonEnabled" class="fab-confirm-enabled" fab fab-right fab-bottom (click)="SaveAndClose()">
        <img src="build/images/iconConfirmEnabled.png" />  
   </button>
```